# creating a mask tensor from an index tensor

Tags: tensorflow

The problem is, I have an indices tensor with shape `[batch_size, seq_len, k]` and every element in this tensor is in range `[0, hidden_dim)`. I want to create a mask tensor with shape `[batch_size, seq_len, hidden_dim]` where every element indexed by the `indices` tensor is `1` and other elements are `0`. `k` is smaller than `hidden_dim`. For example:

```
indices = [[[0],[1],[2]]] #batch_size=1, seq_len=3, k=1
mask = tf.zeros(shape=(1,3,3)) #batch_size=1, seq_len=3, hidden_dim = 3
```

How can I get a target mask tensor whose elements indicated by the `indices` are `1`, i.e.:

```
target_mask = [[[1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1]]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be accomplished using `tf.one_hot`, e.g.:

```py
mask = tf.one_hot(indices, depth=hidden_dim, axis=-1)  # [batch, seq_len, k, hidden_dim]
```

I wasn't clear on what you'd like to happen to `k`. `tf.one_hot()` will keep the axis as is, i.e. you'll get a delta distribution for each [batch-index, seq-index, k-index] tuple.